# Why is this linear vector bundle not trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I need to prove that any smooth section of the following vector bundle vanishes at some point:
$$E_{1,n+1}(\mathbb{R})=\left\{([x],v):[x]\in \mathbb{RP}^n,v=\lambda x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\right\} $$
\begin{align*}\pi:E_{1,n+1}(\mathbb{R})&\to \mathbb{RP}^n\\ 
([x],v)&\mapsto [x] 
\end{align*}
I am not given a differential structure on $E_{1,n+1}(\mathbb{R})$, but I guess if $(\mathcal{U}_i,\varphi_i)$ are the usual charts for the projective space one could adjoin those with the chart sending $v=(v_1,\dots,v_{n+1})$ to $v_i$, i.e. 
$$\hat{\varphi}_i([x],v)= \left(\left(\frac{x_j}{x_i}\right)_{j\neq i},v_i\right)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1},\qquad ([x],v)\in \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{U}_i) $$
In this case the local trivializations may be given by 
$$\phi_i([x],v)=([x],v_i),\qquad ([x],v)\in \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{U}_i) $$
whose local charts expression

$\sigma:\mathbb{RP}^n\to E_{1,n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ is a section if and only if it of the form 
$$ [x]\mapsto ([x],v([x]))$$
for some map $v:\mathbb{RP}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $v([x])=\lambda x$. If $\sigma$ vanishes nowhere, then $\lambda \neq 0$, which means that $[v([x])]=[x]$. Moreover, $\sigma$ is smooth if and only if the map
$$[x]\mapsto v([x]),\qquad [x]\in \mathbb{RP}^n $$
is smooth. I really cannot see how to proceed from here. In fact, I would say that if we choose $v$ so that it maps each $[x]\in \mathbb{RP}^n$ to its unique representative having norm $1$ with $x_1\geq 0$, then this is a smooth section that vanishes nowhere, since in local coordinates 
$$v(\varphi_i^{-1}(x))=\begin{cases}\frac{(x_1,\dots, x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},\dots, x_{n})}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}}& x_1\geq 0 \\ 
-\frac{(x_1,\dots, x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},\dots, x_{n})}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}} & x_1<0\end{cases}, \qquad x\in \varphi_i(\mathcal{U}_i) $$
which is smooth.

Comment: What is the value of $v$ when $x_1 = 0$ ?

Comment: Again, this is not well-defined. For example, what is the image of $(0,1,1)$ ? Is it proportional to $(0,1,1)$ or to $(0,-1,-1)$ ?

Comment: If you read my answer or the one by Andres Mejia, you will see that $\sigma$ does not exist. Look already the case when $n=1$.

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to understand why my example did not work first. Now I see it, so thanks for your remarks.

Comment: Ok sure, I understand !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that every section for $E_n$ vanishes, we can use the intermediate value theorem. In particular, consider a  section $s: \mathbb RP^n \to E_n$.

but we can similarly see that precomposing with the quotient $S^n \to \mathbb RP^n$ yields a map $g:S^n \to E_n$ given by

$$g:x \mapsto ( x,\lambda(x)x),$$
where $t(x) \in \mathbb R$ is a choice of scalar.

Since this map factors through $\mathbb RP^n$, we must have that $g(-x)=g(x)$, or in other words $ (-x,\lambda(-x)(-x))=(x,\lambda(x)x)$
implying that 
 $$\lambda(-x)=-\lambda(x).$$
 Hence, we have a map $\lambda:S^n \to \mathbb R$ that is odd, and so vanishes  by the intermediate value theorem.

---

By the way, there are algebraic topological tools available for this question about real vector bundles. If a real vector bundle possesses a nonvanishing section, then the top stiefel-whitney class must vanish. This can be found in Milnor's book "Characteristic Classes."

Comment: I don't understand why you say $\lambda(-x)=-\lambda(x)$. Here $\lambda$ is a function on $\mathbb{RP}^n$. So shouldn't it be $\lambda(-x)=\lambda(x)$?

Comment: no, because $x,-x$ should map to the same point (as they do in the quotient) but we have that $\lambda(-x)\cdot(-x)=\lambda(x)x$, so it has to be the case that $\lambda(-x)=-\lambda(x)$.

Comment: I guess you mean that $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and $s([x])=([x],\lambda(x)\cdot x)$, so that $\lambda$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. And then $s([-x])=s([x])$ implies $\lambda(x)\cdot x = \lambda(-x)\cdot (-x)$, hence $-\lambda(x)=\lambda(-x)$.

Comment: But that automatically means the second component of $s$ is not a function of $[x]$, I wonder why my approach in writing $s([x])=([x],v([x]))$, with $v([x])\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so that $[v(x)]=[x]$, yields an incorrect result.

Comment: I mean, if $s:[x]\mapsto s([x])$ is defined in $\mathbb{RP}^n$, how is the expression $x\cdot \lambda(x)$ even well defined?

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa I think my notation was unclear and sloppy. Does this answer make more sense?

Comment: Okay, everything is clear now. I did not realize that I just had to compose the section $s$ with the projection map $S^n\to \mathbb{RP}^n$. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, if the section is not zero we can assume it has norm $1$, else we could take $\frac{\sigma}{\|\sigma\|}$. The choice of the vector is not unique though, because for a given line $\ell$ there are two unitary vectors $v,-v$ on $\ell$.

It is now clear that constructing the section boils down to construct a map $\sigma : \Bbb RP^n \to S^n$ with $\pi \circ \sigma = \text{id}_{\Bbb RP^n}$ where $\pi : S^n \to \Bbb RP^n$ is the canonical projection. Such map does not exist, else the covering $S^n \to \Bbb RP^n$ would be trivial, in particular $S^n$ would be disconnected.